# Split the decimal place from a number using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in Table 1

```
In_Stock
5.083
```

How to spit the above value into

```
Carton   Loose
5        0.083
```

Using MS Sql

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that produced the wrong output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at the modulus (`%`) operator?

Comment: SELECT 5.083 - CAST(5.083 AS INT)

Comment: Getting out as 0.08..But i need 0.083

Comment: what if your number is negative? do you want the minus sign or nor? if the decimal is zero do you want zero or blank? you should answer clear question with good variety of sample data. and some people already quickly started answering!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left()` function with `charindex()` :

```
with t as
(
 select 5.083 as nr
)
select left(nr,charindex('.',nr)-1) as Carton,
       nr - left(nr,charindex('.',nr)-1) as Loose
  from t;

Carton  Loose
5       0.083
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e8aaffaea4c185e9beb1e95ff23ee150)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FLOOR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server to accomplish this:

```
SELECT 5.083 AS val, 
FLOOR(5.083) AS rounded_down, 
5.083-FLOOR(5.083) AS diff_between_two
```

Comment: Seductive, but will not work correctly for negative numbers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sure. Based on the in_stock column name, I'm assuming they will not have negative items in stock. Also OP produced a single data row and asked for a solution. Not very comprehensive.

Comment: Absolutely, but for the benefit of future readers with a similar but not identical problem it at least deserves clarification. (That, of course, and there are approaches that do always work without being much more difficult.)

Comment: @dfundako Not to put too fine a hair on things, but you wouldn't expect items in stock to be a decimal number either. So I agree, the question is open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
DECLARE @test decimal(4,3) = 5.083

SELECT @test original 
,      CONVERT(INT, @test) Carton 
,      @test - CONVERT(INT, @test) Loose
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has built-in functions for this purpose, `floor()` and `%`:

```
select floor(field) as integer_portion, field % 1 as fractional_portion
from (values (5.083)) v(field)
```

This should work on any number type.

If you have negative numbers, you might want to check if this does what you really want.

Answer (score -1):

Optionally `ROUND()`:

```
SELECT ROUND(in_stock, 0),
in_stock - Round(in_stock, 0)
FROM inventory
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5130/4

Really there is a TON of ways to math this out. For instance you can get use modulus 1:

```
SELECT ROUND(in_stock, 0),
in_stock % 1
FROM inventory
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5130/6

Comment: produces issue for negative cases such as -5.083

Comment: Round would give you -5 and -.083... would you want a different result?

Comment: Let's ask him :) Btw, realised that my answer also produces -.083 .

Comment: I'm nearly 100% positive he isn't going to have negative stock of an item, but.. who knows. Perhaps they track backorders that way... And if that's the case, then I'm betting -5 and .-083 is probably what they are after.

Comment: If he comes back wanting -6 and .917 I'll eat my hat.